# SYSTEM tables import into other schema in oracle 11g

Tags: oracle, oracle11g

I trying to take oracle DB backup using expdp. I have a specific case where an application table resides in the SYSTEM tablespace.

1. The backup export of this schema is successfully created with options SCHEMAS=SYSTEM and INCLUDE=TABLE:"like 'USER%'" which corresponds to my application tables.
2. I have created another schema with the user impexp which has a different tablespace allocated to it.
   when I try to import the .dmp file into impexp, the import is unsuccessful stating "SYSTEM"."USER_SYS_MAST" exists. 
   Is there a way to import this table in the newly created schema. I also tried using the option REMAP_SCHEMA=SYSTEM:IMPEXP, but it seems to error out saying ORA-39013: Remapping the SYSTEM schema is not supported.

Summarizing : I want to import my application tables in the SYSTEM tablespace into a new TABLESPACE 'IMPEXP'.

Please let me know If I am going wrong somewhere and trying to do something that isn't supported.

any help will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 7):

This is one of the reasons why putting application tables in the SYS or SYSTEM schemas is considered bad practice.  These schemas are vital to the running of our databases and should not be meddled with.

You have compounded this bloomer by naming your tables with a prefix of `USER`, which is the same convention the data dictionary uses.

What you need to do is create a new schema to hold these tables. Grant it whatever privileges it needs that made you think it had to be owned by SYSTEM.  Then move those tables out of the SYSTEM schema.

To do a proper job you should change your application to use this new schema, but as temporary fix you could give SYSTEM rights on the tables and build synonyms for them.  If you have the time, change the application.  It will cause you less grief in the long run.

Either way, you will be able to export the data out of the old database and into the target database using this new schema.

Answer (score 3):

Agree with APC.

In your specific case, I would look at DBMS_METADATA.GET_DDL to extract the DDL so I can recreate all the objects in the new schema. There are options to exclude the TABLESPACE component so they would get created in the new schema's default tablespace.

Then I would simply do INSERT /*+APPEND */ INTO newschema.table AS SELECT * FROM SYSTEM.table

If space is an issue, you may need to TRUNCATE or DROP individual tables immediately after they are successfully copied.

Comment: Thanks APC & Gary, for a quick response..I am implementing the said changes....that should solve my problem.